# Change border-color vuetify v-card when click button

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to change the border color of the `v-card` from `vuetify` with the `limited-products` id to red when the user clicks the `showError` button you can see in the image below, and when the user clicks the `removeError` button, the border color of the v-card with the `limited-products` id becomes white. [In my codepen](https://codepen.io/handy29/pen/dyMWabR), What's wrong with my code? [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you just missing border width.

Edit the `border-color` to `border` like so and your code works fine.

```
<v-card id="limited-products" :style="isShowError ? 'border: 1px solid red;' : 'border: 1px solid white;'">
```

Comment: Not sure that inline styles is the best solution

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap the `v-card` in `v-sheet` like this:

```
<v-sheet outlined color="red" rounded>
    <v-card outlined elevation="0">
        ...
    </v-card>
</v-sheet>
```